# Can't get bootstrap animation to work on divs in a sliding window

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get the text of my slider to fade in as the slider enters ( a carousel type slider my elementor builder has).

To do this I added these to the header of my page in the head section

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

next I added classes to my div of text to show how i wanted it to fade

```
<div class="myDiv animated fadeInLeft" style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;color: #FFF;font-size: 22px;line-height: 27.5px;">Hello World!</div>
```

despite having the classes animated and fadeInLeft, nothing happens.  Everytime the slider slides in, the text is static.  Any ideas?

Comment: We can better help you if you provide small working sample in jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using the good library.

You find `fadeInLeft` on *animate.css*: [here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

I don't think Bootstrap gives you this feature

Comment: Jquery animate is also pretty nice.